# Apache Nutch: Get list of URLs and not content from the entire web

Tags: nutch

I'm very new to apache Nutch. My goal is to start from a list of seed URLs and extract as much URLs (and sub URLs) as I can within a size limit (say no more than 1 million or less than 1 TB of data) using Nutch. I do not need the content of the pages, I only need to save the URLs. Is there any way to do this? Is Nutch the right tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could use Nutch for this purpose, essentially Nutch does all of what you want.

You need to parse the fetched HTML in either way (in order to discover new links, and of course repeat the process). One way to go would be to dump the LinkDB that Nutch keeps into a file using the `linkdb` command. Our you could use the `indexer-links` plugin that is available for Nutch 1.x to index your inlinks/outlinks into Solr/ES.

In Nutch you control how many URLs you want to process per round, but this is hardly related to the amount of fetched data. So you'll need to decide when to stop.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Do you know where I can download the http://rdf.dmoz.org/rdf/content.rdf.u8.gz data? The Nutch page recommended this but they have shut down the website. I need this to generate a seed list.

Comment: Honestly I've no idea. I thought that my previous comment was about a different thing.